# Selenium automation interview preperation question

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, interview

What error does this line return when I pass a URL without HTTPS or HTTP

```
driver.get("www.google.com");
```

It was asked to a fresher in his interview.

Comment: Have you tried this statement in your script?

Comment: I do not see any value in this, OP wants others to run a piece of code for him and paste the error.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is a stupid question to ask in an interview, because it asks a very specific detail of how to use WebDriver that I have not really thought about in the 10 years I am using Selenium, but this might a great answer:

- **I don't know**, but I could try and see what happens. Why do you ask? Did you have problems with this in the past?

I have just tried removing HTTPS with WebDriver C#, but it uses `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl()`, it gives:

> Message: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : invalid argument
>   (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)

I think it might be different depending on language and or browser driver implementation.

There might be a **risk** that leaving out the HTTPS it could default to HTTP, thus not testing the HTTPS version of the site. I do think HTTP should always redirect to HTTPS and you should only test one version.

Comment: Besides the browser itself, there are extensions and configurations to always for HTTPS. The answer is very contextual.

Comment: You already *tried* to explain an answer to this question (which shows why the question is not stupid!)

Comment: @masoodghz Maybe, I have updated my answer to explain why I think it is a stupid question :)

Answer (score 5):

This question is about WebDriver W3C specification. As per the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#navigate-to) any implementation has to follow:

> If url is not an absolute URL or is not an absolute URL with fragment or not a local scheme, return [error with error code invalid argument](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-invalid-argument).

Answer (score 3):

If you try to open a URL without http or https (for e.g. `driver.get(“www.facebook.com”);`), `get()` method will throw an error `“org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException“`.

It will also gives error message as `“Cannot navigate to invalid URL”.`